# License for Glassfish javax.servlet servlet-api version 2.5?

Tags: servlets, glassfish, licensing

Anyone know where I can find proof of the license for javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5??? The META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file in servlet-api.jar file indicates that it is a component of the Glassfish Application Server, but I've downloaded Glassfish versions back to version 1 and can't find anything that conclusively says the bundled version of servlet-api is 2.5.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The servlet-api 2.5 jar files can be found on Maven Central at: [http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|javax.servlet|servlet-api|2.5|jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.servlet%7Cservlet-api%7C2.5%7Cjar)
While the binary jar file does not contain a license file, the sources jar file includes the the CDDLv1.0 license and a link to https://glassfish.dev.java.net/public/CDDLv1.0.html in the java file headers.

Comment: Additionally the file `package.html` mentions unknown Sun Microsystems license, which may be an issue with assuming it's CDDL: 

`Copyright 2001 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
This software is the proprietary information of Sun Microsystems, Inc.  
Use is subject to license terms.`

Answer (score 0):

> GlassFish Server supports the Java Servlet Specification version 3.0.

and

> Servlet API version 3.0 is fully backward compatible with versions
>   2.3, 2.4, and 2.5, so all existing servlets should work without modification or recompilation.

(see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beagj.html) Oracle page)

The servlet api can be found in `GLASSFISH_ROOT/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet.jar` (you may have a look at the `MANIFEST.MF`)

Comment: So, if I need proof of the license under which the servlet-api jar was released, you're advocating upgrading to version 3.0+ for which there is an associatable license file...?

Comment: I guess this is your best option :)

Comment: That's a possibility - I would certainly think that, given the number of projects that depend on this jar, there should be an attributable license though...